# Question on async vs sync queries on database

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js

I have a promise that performs 3 queries at the same time on my database

```
async parallel(){
   Promise.all([client.query('SELECT * FROM books where book_id = $1' 
   ['bookid']), client.query('SELECT * FROM username where username = $2', 
   ['username']), client.query('SELECT * FROM saved where saved_id = $3', 
   ['saved_id']))
   .then(queryResults => {
        console.log(queryResults[0]);
        console.log(queryResults[1]);
        console.log(queryResults[2]);
   })
}
```

If 100 users perform that same query at the same moment, would my database would be running 300 queries at the same moment?

Would it be better to do a synchronous query where the first query, runs 100 simultaneous queries, followed by another 100, and the last 100 so that the database has to deal with less concurrent requests at the same moment?

Comment: Did you never heard about Proxy server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JackBashford says, the `client` object represents a single database connection, and only one query can run through a connection at a time.

If you actually wanted to run all 3 queries concurrently, you would have to create 3 different clients, and then the code would look like:

```
async parallel(){
   Promise.all([client1.query('SELECT * FROM books where book_id = $1' 
   ['bookid']), client2.query('SELECT * FROM username where username = $2', 
   ['username']), client3.query('SELECT * FROM saved where saved_id = $3', 
   ['saved_id']))
   .then(queryResults => {
        console.log(queryResults[0]);
        console.log(queryResults[1]);
        console.log(queryResults[2]);
   })
}
```

And indeed, if 100 users ran this code at the same time, you'd get 300 concurrent queries. Depending on how you have your database configured, you might run out of server connections and some of them will fail.

Comment: So for example in my code, lets say each query took one second to perform. My database would be running 100 concurrent queries in the first second, 100 again in the next  second and another 100 in the third second?

Comment: Yes, that's what will probably happen.

Answer (score 1):

The `client` object can only run a single query at a time - so the queries will not run simultaneously, but in series.

Comment: Would that mean if 100 users were performing that query only 100 queries would be running at the same time in the databse?

Comment: Not sure - either that, or 100 queries would run one after the other. But not all 300 simultaneously.

Comment: @WHOATEMYNOODLES Are you creating a new `client` object for every request you process?

Comment: No I'm only using the same client for the entire query. I'm also using pools so I hope I don't run out of server connections